# Dyno's Management on Heroku with Unicorn

Tags: heroku, resque, unicorn

I was using 2 web dynos 1 worker dyno and 1 resque dyno before My application was working fine. But suddenly I increase the total number of dynos made 4 web dynos , 2 resque dynos and 2 worker dynos. This hampers the performance of my application.

Some Times error messages

[NewRelic][02/04/14 04:33:18 +0000 163ac5c4-qwqq-4271-b38a-absajsg2323s (19)] ERROR : Mysql2::Error: User 'b0ffsaasbffa' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 15)

Please tell me what should I do ?

Comment: How many worker processes do you have configured for Unicorn to use? You've consumed all your MYSQL connections so you need to increase the number of connections or decrease the number of processes creating connections.

Comment: worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're running 4 dynos with 3 unicorn worker processes each you're using 12 connections there for a start. It sounds like you are using a DB plan that restricts the number of connections.

Heroku have a very good article on concurrency and how database connections work at - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections which is worth reading.

Comment: As per my DB plan I can use maximum 15 connections.

Comment: right, so some of those connections can go bad so they would still count, then you've got your Heroku workers too.

Comment: Ok. So what should I have to do with it. Should I increase the connections or just reduce the Dynos? But I don't want to limit the no. of users using my application.